# problem of importing tensorflow within jupyter notebook

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, jupyter

I tried to import tensorflow. But the following came out. Please. Does anyone have a clue about fixing the problem?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tDGn.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qY5iT.png) I haven't found anyone run into such long errortype description. For details, pleas take a look at the attached png file. Thanks.

16 DESCRIPTOR = _descriptor_pool.Default().AddSerializedFile(b'\n1tensorflow/tsl/protobuf/coordination_config.proto\x12\ntensorflow"1\n\x0e\x43oordinatedJob\x12\x0c\n\x04name\x18\x01 \x01(\t\x12\x11\n\tnum_tasks\x18\x02 \x01(\x05"\xdd\x02\n\x19\x43oordinationServiceConfig\x12\x14\n\x0cservice_type\x18\x01 \x01(\t\x12\x16\n\x0eservice_leader\x18\x02 \x01(\t\x12\x1b\n\x13\x65nable_health_check\x18\x03 \x01(\x08\x12&\n\x1e\x63luster_register_timeout_in_ms\x18\x04 \x01(\x03\x12\x1f\n\x17heartbeat_timeout_in_ms\x18\x05 \x01(\x03\x12\x38\n\x14\x63oordinated_job_list\x18\n \x03(\x0b\x32\x1a.tensorflow.CoordinatedJob\x12&\n\x1eshutdown_barrier_timeout_in_ms\x18\x07 \x01(\x03\x12*\n"agent_destruction_without_shutdown\x18\x08 \x01(\x08\x12\x18\n\x10recoverable_jobs\x18\t \x03(\tJ\x04\x08\x06\x10\x07\x42WZUgithub.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go/core/protobuf/for_core_protos_go_protob\x06proto3')

TypeError: Couldn't build proto file into descriptor pool!
Invalid proto descriptor for file "tensorflow/tsl/protobuf/coordination_config.proto":
tensorflow.CoordinationServiceConfig.service_type: "tensorflow.CoordinationServiceConfig.service_type" is already defined in file "tensorflow/core/protobuf/coordination_config.proto".
tensorflow.CoordinationServiceConfig.service_leader: "tensorflow.CoordinationServiceConfig.service_leader" is already defined in file "tensorflow/core/protobuf/coordination_config.proto".
tensorflow.CoordinationServiceConfig.enable_health_check: "tensorflow.CoordinationServiceConfig.enable_health_check" is already defined in file "tensorflow/core/protobuf/coordination_config.proto".
tensorflow.CoordinationServiceConfig.cluster_register_timeout_in_ms: "tensorflow.CoordinationServiceConfig.cluster_register_timeout_in_ms" is already defined in file "tensorflow/core/protobuf/coordination_config.proto".
tensorflow.CoordinationServiceConfig.heartbeat_timeout_in_ms: "tensorflow.CoordinationServiceConfig.heartbeat_timeout_in_ms" is already defined in file "tensorflow/core/protobuf/coordination_config.proto".
tensorflow.CoordinationServiceConfig: "tensorflow.CoordinationServiceConfig" is already defined in file "tensorflow/core/protobuf/coordination_config.proto".

I tried to import tensorflow. I googled it and couldn't find the exact situation anyone run into.Someone suggested reinstalling Protobuf to deal with the similar type of problem(TypeError: Couldn't build proto file into descriptor pool!) But doesn't work for me. Not sure if it is related, but I am using surface laptop 5.

Comment: Hi @Wong Peter, Which system OS are you using and How did you install TensorFlow in your system? Please check this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-native) to install TensorFlow and follow the step by step instructions mentioned in the link as per your system OS. Let us know if the issue still persists.

Comment: Hi @Wong Peter, Could you please try executing the code after installing protobuf 3.20 using `pip install protobuf==3.20`? Let us know if the issue still persists.